# Scope for 5 pages related to each other

Tags: jsf

Iam developing an Application using JSF2.2. I have situation where i have 5 webpages which are related to eachother, user will enter the values in each webpage and finally click on submit. The user can Click submit after entering data into all 5 pages or in any page he can click submit. In each page he clicks SAVE to save data .I have to capture the user data and insert into database when he clicks SUBMIT. If i use JSF @RequestScope the values scope will expire when the user moves to another page. How do i handle this situation?? Please correct me if iam wrong anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If `@RequestScoped` is to short, `@SessionScoped` seems to be the best option. For session scoped beans, the bean lives as long as the HTTP session. From your description it not entirely clear how long a session typically takes, but if a user typically only enters that information during a session, `@SessionScoped` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank for the reply Hoopje... In the same session the user can enter the details multiple times... Once he clicks on submit and the data gets saved in database he can again enter data into the same forms in the same session.... For eg, if a he's entering user details say demographic details of some person in 1 page and work experience in second page. I need to save both these details when he clicks submit.. After which he can enter details of  another person.... If I use session scopescope how do I invalidate only the bean data

Comment: @tiny he doesn't enter simultaneously but 1 after the other... He clicks save and proceeds to the next page and finally clicks submit....

Comment: @Hoopje: The codi/deltaspike `@ViewAccessScoped` is better. And if the 'pages' are rendered in the same 'page' via includes, the @ViewScoped can even be enough